# types/ws Type 'Server' is not generic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Suddenly getting this error:

```
TypeScript: ./..\..\node_modules\@types\ws\index.d.ts:328:18
       Type 'Server' is not generic.


Angular CLI: 13.3.11
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.4.0
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package Version
@angular-devkit/architect 0.1303.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular 13.3.11
@angular-devkit/core 13.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics 13.3.11
@angular/cli 13.3.11
@angular/pwa 13.3.11
@schematics/angular 13.3.11
rxjs 6.6.7
typescript 5.1.3
```

Already tried to update @types/ws to version ^8.13.0 with no success

Comment: Enable skipLibCheck?

Comment: @zenly skipLibCheck didn't work. any other suggestion?

Comment: Any other suggestion? Getting the same issue on Angular 15

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue
`npm i @types/ws@8.5.4` worked for me.

Comment: this worked, thank you so much ! Not to forget to eventually delete package-log.json and then running npm install again.

Answer (score 5):

I had a pretty old version of `@types/node` defined in my package.json which did not match my actual version of Node.js.

i removed that explicit dependency with
`npm uninstall @types/node` (and let npm do the magic with an actual peer dependency).

Comment: Sound good :)


Didnae work :(

Answer (score 3):

I spent two days on this updating and downgrading @types/node and @types/express. In the end I updated my angular project from 14 to 15 and everything worked perfectly again.

Comment: I am on angular 15 and it still returns the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AsafEpelbaum try `npm i --save @types/ws@8.5.4`

Comment: thanks @SalminSkenderovic! I guess downgrading is the answer until 8.5.5 is fixed

Comment: @salminSkeenderovic Yes, downgrading to @types/ws@8.5.4 eliminates the error. thanks

Comment: >>  npm i --save @types/ws@8.5.4         
worked for me. thank you @AsafEpelbaum

Comment: I had the same problem. Downgrading to 8.5.4 worked for me -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue in the build pipeline of a -fairly old- Angular project. Peculiarly, it failed every other build, since June 2023. I managed to resolve the issue as explained below. My solution is based on the remark of [Salmin Skenderovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5539577/salmin-skenderovic) below the answer of [Zen Donegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8790128/zen-donegan).

1. In packages.json, I have added this dependency:

   "@types/ws" : "<8.5.5",

The assumption is that the bug is in @types/ws v8.5.5, so until it is fixed we want to use any version *below* 8.5.5.

2. Before compiling, I needed to run this once:

   npm i --legacy-peer-deps

This command updates **package-lock.json**. This configuration file "freezes" all Angular dependencies for the project to a currently working set.

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this error, I discovered that it was due to an issue in my `@types/node` package. I was on version 17 when I got the error. Every other major version I tried worked fine, no error.

So I don't think it is actually an issue with the ws module, as others have suggested, but rather an issue between ws and certain versions of @types/node.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the folder `node_modules/@types/ws` and that worked for me.
Next time I'll install my package using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Reinstalling my packages using the --legacy-peer-deps option worked for me indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but additionally I got following message: `../node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:72:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'AbortSignal' must be of type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }', but here has type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; }'.`

So, what I did is simply added two lines of code to the global.d.ts to the `AbortSignal` variable, as it was stated in the error message (btw there was already TODO comment from developers):

```js
declare var AbortSignal: {
    prototype: AbortSignal;
    new(): AbortSignal;
    // TODO: Add abort() static
    abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; // <--------------lines which I added
    timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; //------|
};
```

After that, converting to JS was without problems :)